# Javascript Compare Objects to Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/PhilFromHeck/KzSxT/

In this fiddle, you can see at line 38 in the Javascript that I've attempted to make a comparison that isn't working. I believe it because one of the variables is an Object, where the other is an Element; does anyone have any advice as to how I can can find a match between these two?

```
menuID[0] = document.getElementById('menuOne'); 
menuID[1] = document.getElementById('menuTwo'); 
menuID[2] = document.getElementById('menuThree'); 
menuID[3] = document.getElementById('menuFour'); 
$('.menu').mouseenter(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if(menuID[i] == $(this)){
      //this condition is not met, there's an alert which will add more detail in the fiddle
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Method `document.getElementById` returns a DOM element an not a jQuery object. In the `mouseenter` event handler `this` refers to a DOM element as well.

So in order to compare them you shouldn't convert `this` to a jQuery object:

```
if (menuID[i] === this) { ... }
```

Comment: I didn't think of that.  That's probably better than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use jQuery's [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) for this.

```
if($(this).is(menuID[i])){
```

Comment: Less jQuery, not more is the better answer here.  Yes; this will work, but you're basically wrapping and then unwrapping the object, when all you want is the object itself.

Comment: @Retsam: Yeah, I realized that.  I'll leave this here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues I see here:

One is simply that, in your jsfiddle, the first 4 lines of code that you list aren't running before the bottom block runs.  I'm not sure why you have both an init function that you attach to window.onload and a document.ready() function; but you'll want to make sure that init runs.

Secondly; as VisioN said, I think the main issue is that you're trying to compare a jQuery wrapper around a DOM element `$(this)` with a DOM element (the result of `getElementById`).  As he says, `this == menuID[i]` will work.

At a design level, why not simply use the id to identify the element?  `this.id` will give you the the id; why not simply use that to determine which menu div you're looking at?